# Transfer from Inkscape to Cricut Design Space messes up svg

Tags: inkscape, svg

I edited an svg in Inkscape, downloaded it (save as) and uploaded it to Cricut design space. When I first saw the upload, it only had a few dots filled in over the background color. Once fully loaded onto my canvas, it showed an outline of my previously solid area. I tried opening the svg outside of design space and it worked fine. I added a few pictures. The first is my svg in inkscape, the second is the svg on the cricut upload screen, and the third is when it's in the design space canvas. I tried uploading it with the files next to each other instead of overlapping and had the same problem.
[image: svg in inkscape]
[image: svg on upload screen]
[image: svg on design space canvas]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This is hard to answer without access to the SVG. Did the SVG open OK in Inkscape? What software was used to make the original SVG? Not all SVGs will work well in Inkscape. What did you edit in Inkscape?  How did you save it from Inkscape?  Did you use Plain SVG as the format? Sometimes other software might have difficulty with a regular Inkscape SVG. Another possibility is that you haven't combined the paths properly. These are all just guesses though.

Comment: I would give access to the svg but I don't know how since I'm a bit new to inkscape. Sorry! I made the svg off of an online picture. I used an online svg converter and imported it to inkscape to edit it. It worked fine in inkscape and when I opened the edited file in images in microsoft edge it appeared fine as well. I saved it as an inkscape svg but I just tried saving it as a plain svg and had the same effect.

Comment: You can upload it to svgshare.com - no need for an account, just paste the link here. I could take a look and see if there's anything obvious, no promises though.